# How to parse JSON with multiple instance in Object C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use NSJSONSerialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356842/how-to-use-nsjsonserialization)

I am testing to use the web service of my website on iphone Application.
The JSON with problem is that:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Jason1",
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "Jason2",
        "age": 40
    },
    {
        "name": "Jason3",
        "age": 60
    }
]
```

And my codes:

```
   NSData *jasonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/all_personal_information.json"]];
    NSDictionary *json = nil;
    if (jasonData) {
        json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jasonData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    }
```

The code work fine with `{"name":"jason","age":20}`
and I can get the values by using `json[@"name"]` and `json[@"age"]`

But i don't know how to get the value from the JSON with problem.
I tried to use  `[json enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions]` to transverse the dictionary.
But I will get an error:

```
enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89b2490
```

But I can get the full JSON when I Log the `[json description]` into console.

Comment: It's not `jason`, it's `JSON`.

Comment: jason is my name just for testing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take it in an array.. for example

```
NSData *jasonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/all_personal_information.json"]];
NSDictionary *json = nil;
if (jasonData) {
    NSError *e = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jasonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
}
```

the array will contain your

```
{
 "name": "Jason1",
 "age": 20
}
```

etc in its individual indexes. when u want to get the values in it, you can use this below method to get the values

```
NSDictionary *userName = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *stringName = [userName valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: it is simple but works :) I did not keep in mind the return type is a id pointer. I always think the return type is NSDictionary.
So NSDictionary is only about key-value pair. And NSArray is about an array of any object ???

Comment: yes.. its quite simple.. glad i cud help :)

Comment: do you mean mark the best answer ??

Comment: return type is not exactly dictionary.. n yes.. array can be of any object..

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a dictionary while you get an array. If you do the following it should work:

```
id json = nil;
if (jasonData)
{
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jasonData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
}

if ([json isKindOfClass:NSArray.class])
{
    for (id personDef in json)
    {
        if ([personDef isKindOfClass:NSDictionary.class])
        {
            NSDictionary * dict = (NSDictionary *) moduleDef;

            NSString * name  = [dict objectForKey:@"name" withClass:NSString.class];

            NSLog(@"Person: @%", name);
        }
    }
}
```

In here I do some additional checking if the objects are the ones we expect. If this isn't the case you should add (proper) error handling.

Comment: Good try :) I hope I understand your code and fixed some syntax mistake. But I still cannot finish the task.[link]http://chopapp.com/#n5y1m9tk[link]. the label shows that this is not NSArray.

Comment: OOO I made a mistake, I forgot to turn on my server

Answer (score 1):

it will help you.

```
     NSMutableDictionary *CompaintsAry =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:respo options:kNilOptions error:&error];
     NSMutableArray *tempary =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0;i < [CompaintsAry count];i++) {
    CfResultFatch *rs = [[CfResultFatch alloc] initWithName:[[CompaintsAry obj ectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Name"]
                                                     cipd :[[CompaintsAry objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Age"]];

    [tempary addObject:rs];
}
cfComlaintsLists = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:tempary];
SelectComplain = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[cfComlaintsLists count]]; 
[chiftab reloadData];
```

Comment: Beware, there are 4 unreleased objects here.

Comment: I did not test it because I don't know what is CfResultFatch. But thanks for you answer :)

Comment: What is `CfResultFatch`?  Using Google, I haven't been able to find any useful reference to this class or even the selector `initWithName:cipd:`, though I have found similar sample code on other sites.