# Parsing NSDictionary data from JSONValue as a string

Tags: ios, json, nsurlconnection

I just fetched data but when i try to append it to string from NSData , compiler occurs Exception error . 
My code seems like this:

```
NSDictionary *allDAtaDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_webData options:0 error:nil];
NSString *jSonStatus = [allDAtaDictionary objectForKey:@"status"];
if([jSonStatus isEqualToString:@"OK"])
{
   NSDictionary *results = [allDAtaDictionary objectForKey:@"user_details"];
   NSLog(@"User Details :  %@",results);
```

All things works well until these line just starts:

```
NSString *userID = [results objectForKey:@"userID"];
```

The error output is :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9485a00'

and this is my jSOn output , NSLog(@"User Details :  %@",results);

```
User Details :  (
        {
        userCity = California;
        userCountry = "United States";
        userDOB = "1988-03-02";
        userDetails = "";
        userEmail = "xxx@xxx.com";
        userFBID = 715296184;
        userFullName = "John Mc Grager";
        userGender = Male;
        userID = 70;
        userLastLoginTime = "2013-05-29 10:51:27";
        userLatitude = "37.7858";
        userLongtitude = "-122.406";
        userNickName = warblader;
        userPassword = "";
        userStatus = 1;
        userToken = "";
    }
)
```

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time someone asked this same question...Well, the clue is right at the end of the first line above!

Comment: What do you think `__NSCFArray` means?

Comment: @borrrden , I wish you would read carefully what i have asked for help...

Comment: I read it well enough: you failed to understand the object you were getting and were treating it as a dictionary instead of an array (i.e. `__NSCFArray` which is the huge clue to the entire problem).  Unlike the poster below I don't plan to hand you such an easy answer on a silver platter.  Instead I think it would be better for you to understand what went wrong.

Comment: ye ye u wrote nickel ... instead of write something, very brave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the JSON is  an array with one dictionary in it. What you show us here at least.

So

```
NSArray *results = [allDAtaDictionary objectForKey:@"user_details"];
NSLog(@"User Details :  %@",results);

assert(results.count>0);
NSDictionary *user = [results objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *userID = [results objectForKey:@"userID"];
NSLog(@"%@", userID);
```

Comment: You made my day ! Services pushes me data with in array's 1. element than I have to convert it in to  Dictionary of 0. th array index.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need save use the serialised data into an array.. Then you have to use it accordingly .. in this case

```
NSArray *allDAtaDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_webData options:0 error:nil];
```

Log the array in index 0 and the see what you are getting. After this you can start parsing the data.

The exception is occuring due to this. Check my answer here to parse JSON [How to parse JSON with multiple instance in Object C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757706/how-to-parse-json-with-multiple-instance-in-object-c/12757869#12757869)

Answer (score 0):

Your response probably has An array in it, which **result** Dictionary is being holding, so you need to use ObjectAtIndex rather calling objectForKey