# Download JSON data via NSJSONSerialization

Tags: iphone, json, sqlite, fmdb, nsjsonserialization

I have a JSON string from PHP's `json_encode()`. This is how it looks in [JSONViewer.stack.hu](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://j4hm.t15.org/ios/jsonnews.php), and this is how it looks in the [browser](http://j4hm.t15.org/ios/jsonnews.php).

Is it possible to use NSJSONSerialization to download the JSON data directly? If so, I am going to save the downloaded JSON data to SQLite by using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id jsonObjectFromUrlString(NSString *urlString)
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSError *error = nil;
    id jsonObject = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    else
        jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    return jsonObject;
}
```

Comment: Will it be able do download the JSON data in the site? I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Why don't you try it and print out the results?

Comment: I was able to output it using NSLog: `(
        {
        article = "This is a dummy article about Apple Releases iPad 3";
        "date_string" = "1969-12-31 19:00:05";
        id = 1;
        timestamp = 5;
        title = "Apple Releases iPad 3";
    }, {...;}, {...;}
        )`

Answer (score 1):

JSON Serialization method. please refer this. 
[JSON Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10347317/696145)

for database did you look at coredata. 
please have a look at these ones.

[add core data to existing xcode project.](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/08/08/add-core-data-to-an-existing-project-in-xcode-4/)

[A simple intro to use coreData](http://remapps.net/2012/02/07/adding-core-data-to-a-project/)

Comment: Yeah, I have looked into Core Data. Unfortunately, I haven't fully grasped its idea yet so I'm sticking with FMDB for the mean time.

Comment: the problem is simple when you use restkit or something like it you can create models directly that and reduce your processing time for the app to run correctly.

Comment: nope...It is id. It takes the form of NSArray if the data you get is an array and NSDictionary if you get just a object. Totally depends that comes up.

Comment: Yah, it took the form of NSArray. So, did I downloaded the JSON data?