# JSON parsing using ios

Tags: objective-c, json, ios5

I use the following code

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response 
                                                     options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments                                                           
                                                       error:&err];
```

first I want to add 2 options `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments`, and `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`

if I used only `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` the code will crash

now if the response is just string true or false , how to compare the value of NSArray to string "false" for example

I cannot say for example `[jsonArray objectatindex:0]`

any idea how to make my code intellegent enough such that if only the response is array of object or only string

Comment: You can check length of array for this. If length is 1 then again check value of array at index 0 for true/false.

Comment: I cannot check for count , it will crash too

Comment: First check if `jsonArray` is nil. If it is check the `err`. Chances are the `response` is invalid, NSLog `response` and insure it is valid json. Basic debugging, check the inputs.

Comment: it's not nil , it's just contain the false string , but am not sure how to check it , I cannot say objectatindexof , or count , ....

Comment: Check `jsonArray` with `NSLog`. To find the class of `jsonArray`: `NSLog(@"class type: %@", NSStringFromClass([jsonArray class]);`

Comment: Take a look on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356842/how-to-use-nsjsonserialization

Comment: As I told in my example first check class type and if it is NSString type, then it means your string is true or false.

Comment: `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` is not a valid option for `JSONObjectWithData` when you expect an `NSArray`. Apple docs: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
Specifies that the parser should allow top-level objects that are not an instance of NSArray or NSDictionary.

Comment: @Zaph the class is class type: __NSCFString how to extract the string within it , there is no isequaltostring

Comment: @Zaph it's part of options enum NSJSONReadingAllowFragments

Comment: `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` is not valid for a return type of `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before working on response check Class type.

```
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response 
                                                 options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments                                                           
                                                   error:&err];

if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    // Do stuff for array.
}
else if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
   // Do stuff for dictionary
}

else if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
   // Do stuff for string
}
```

Comment: what do u mean by the jsonData , is it the jsonArray , also how to add multiple options

Comment: see my edit. jsonArray is like jsonObject and I have change djsonData with response

Comment: it's type of   __NSCFString how to extract the data of it I mean I cannot say isequal to string or any other data

Comment: By placing above code in which block your control goes, during debugging check it and tell me

Comment: thanks a lot it work very well , I will test against dictionary and Nssarray

Comment: am sorry but will the option NSJSONReadingAllowFragments will read dictionary or nssarray

Comment: If you are facing problem then you can use NilOption for the same. Because I am not sure about NSJSONReadingAllowFragments. Because I never tested it on my end.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24621/discussion-between-best-coder-and-amh)

Answer (score 0):

The returned JSON is a fragment that is an `NSString`, `count` is not valid for strings. Change the return type:

```
NSString *jsonString = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response 
                                                     options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments                                                           
                                                       error:&err];

NSLog(@"jsonArray: %@, length: %d", jsonString, jsonString.length);
```

Then do whatever you want with the string.

Generally JSON is an array or a dictionary, in this case it is a string, possibly the JSON is not correctly formatted.