# Objective C how to decode two dimensional array encoded in Json

Tags: objective-c, json

I have the next php script:

```
<?PHP
$results = array(
    array(
        'col1'=>'val1.1',
        'col2'=>'val1.2'
    ),
    array(
        'col1'=>'val2.1',
        'col2'=>'val2.2'
    )
);
echo json_encode($results);

?>
```

Every array from the main array represents a raw from a database.
The results variable is sent to an OSx app.
I'm trying to decode the json string to sync a local database with a remote database.

I'm using this code:

```
NSError *error = nil;
id object = [NSJSONSerialization
                     JSONObjectWithData:receivedData
                     options:0
                     error:&error];

if(error) { /* JSON was malformed, act appropriately here */ }
if([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
  NSDictionary *results = object;       
  NSLog(@"%@",results);
}else{
  NSLog(@"there is not an JSON object");
}
```

The problem is the app is not recognise the received string as an object. Can some one explain me why and what I'm doing wrong?

The string received is:

```
[{"col1":"val1.1","col2":"val1.2"},{"col1":"val2.1","col2":"val2.2"}]
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to use NSJSONSerialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356842/how-to-use-nsjsonserialization).  Your object is an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary.

Comment: Go to json.org and spend 5-10 minutes studying the syntax diagram.  That's all it takes to learn the language, and then you won't have to puzzle over what you have anymore.

Comment: just add `header('Content-type: application/json');` this line to your PHP code before `echo json_encode($results);` this line, and it will send json response back, and in response first object is an `Array` not `Dictionary` so read array then dictionary.