# Facebook API response Xcode Parse

Tags: ios, xcode, json, facebook, parsing

I am working on Project to Parse Facebook Graph API response in Xcode. Got Success in getting response but I am newBee to Parse Facebook API response via Xcode.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "Sports", 
      "name": "TennisClubbers", 
      "access_token": "CAACEdEose0cBACQZCQkbeQjW4NpjxTHU6Hdr4vErEhvAQhAlraGJuNkoa76tXn9keSFGGRW2YXEaPe6LzNwkOeN9YFFX02g7QvHDbmUFeYcFh2oEjAHrdgmxyEL9NwvTH7R5B3LKvILhfZCpluLg6VjLcYBsNmOxKKOhFVqusJtblDzv7zoZAJC2GkEmdXs1R65f9meVwZDZD", 
      "perms": [
        "ADMINISTER", 
        "EDIT_PROFILE", 
        "CREATE_CONTENT", 
        "MODERATE_CONTENT", 
        "CREATE_ADS", 
        "BASIC_ADMIN"
      ], 
      "id": "330130543706625"
    }, 
    {
      "category": "Sports", 
      "name": "SoccerClubbers", 
      "access_token": "CAACEdEose0cBAAVinXUUr6nzZCJeWExBPOYV3RltkutoDLOMcsqh4o52Cg0utC15HJI20u9ezFMsIl9SquVVZBWWHIbTC36U0PH8K9k0rgCANxSafdkuDE71sluPuFqPF4sVsO3tnlKu7DsxQf9TjKEZAVrl0sIouZBGMkopcVllaT1ARhg3SDFIyQZAyxKrZCRHxitnIFsgZDZD", 
      "perms": [
        "ADMINISTER", 
        "EDIT_PROFILE", 
        "CREATE_CONTENT", 
        "MODERATE_CONTENT", 
        "CREATE_ADS", 
        "BASIC_ADMIN"
      ], 
      "id": "239810846118768"
    }
  ],
```

Can anyone share XCode lines to parse Facebook API response Data & get Category,Names & ID in separate variables.

Comment: I would suggest looking at one of the many existing JSON parsers out there. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/best-json-library-to-use-when-developing-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 0):

I have previously used Parse in one of my project. I don't remember correctly but I guess If you are using FBRequest to obtain the above data, then they should be already parsed. In other words the data you have got should already be parsed in NSDictionary or NSArray depending on json data's root object.

If not you can easily parse a json data using NSJSONSerialization class provided by ios

Comment: Can you share code to Parse it if possible - Waiting

Comment: For json serialization check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356842/how-to-use-nsjsonserialization)

Comment: Check this parse.com [documentation](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios) especially the section "Requesting and Setting User Data". Here you can see the response received from facebook ios sdk is already parsed.