# IOS6 JSON.H import in main viewcontroller (Xcode5)

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode, ios6

I am new to ios,so inorder to get accesstoken, i followed the link 
 http://technogerms.com/login-with-google-using-oauth-2-0-for-ios-xcode-objective-c/ .so in these link they used json.h files are they mandatory.if it is yes then explain me about json github in these link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link what you want.

https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

Answer (score 0):

There is no compulsory to use JSON.h in your project. Now You can use inbuilt apple JSON parser. IF you want to download JSon library then link is

[Download JSon file from here](http://ge.tt/57ghpW01/v/0)

Otherwise you can use this Inbuilt apple JSON Parser by using following method.

```
 NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves || NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&myError];
```

The full code is as below:

```
 NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@listcontact.php?uid=%@&page=0",LocalPath,appdel.strid]; //---- Add your URL for webservice-----

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

 NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

 There are two NSURLConnection request methods AsynchronousRequest and SynchronousRequest.

 (1) For AsynchronousRequest

 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     NSError *error1;
     NSDictionary *res=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error1];
 }];

 (2) For SynchronousRequest

   NSData *GETReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
   NSError *myError = nil;

   NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:GETReply options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];
```

Comment: I want to use apple JSON Parser explain me the code u have provided,and where to place and how? Thanks

Comment: @ChetanKumar See my updated code. If you have any query then you can contact me

Answer (score 0):

Use native NSJSONSerialization class, you can find more info on below link,

[iOS NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[How to use NSJSONSerialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356842/how-to-use-nsjsonserialization)