# parse a simple json string without object name

Tags: ios, json, parsing

This may be a very simple answer but I cant find a good tutorial to help me. I am trying to parse a json string that I had returned from a http post the json string looks like this when I log it:

```
(
        {
        "ADD_CITY" = BEDFORD;
        "ADD_LINE1" = "100 COURT AVE";
        "ADD_LINE2" = "";
        "ADD_STATE" = IA;
        "ADD_ZIP" = 50833;
        "BUSINESS_NAME" = "";
        "FIRST_NAME" = JOHN;
        "LAST_NAME" = DOE;
    },
        {
        "ADD_CITY" = BEDFORD;
        "ADD_LINE1" = "101 COURT AVE";
        "ADD_LINE2" = "";
        "ADD_STATE" = IA;
        "ADD_ZIP" = 50833;
        "BUSINESS_NAME" = "";
        "FIRST_NAME" = BOB;
        "LAST_NAME" = JOHNSON;
    }
)
```

I am trying to make so I can insert each value of each place into a coredata table that I have made but I am getting stuck parsing this into something I can work with. I have read I have to do something with using NSJSONSerialization.

**edit**

```
-(void)getLocations{
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"code": @"123"};
[manager POST:@"website.com/getjson" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    response = responseObject;
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
}
```

Comment: That's not JSON at all. If it was just changing `(...)` to `[...]`, it would be easy to fix, but it has a number of other deviations: using `=` instead of `:`, using `;` instead of `,`, and using unquoted strings. You'll have to write your own parser.

Comment: This is the `description` of the object you got from your JSON after deserialization (an `NSArray` in this case containing two `NSDictionaries`). Just enumerate it and you'll be good to go...

Comment: That's an NSArray of two NSDictionaries.  What problem are you having with it?

Comment: @ikegami I added the code that I am using to get my log, hope that helps make sense of things.

Comment: @Alladinian can you give me a brief example of how this would look so I can get off to a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFNetworking already done this for you (the deserialization from the JSON). So you could just enumerate and create your objects accordingly for storing in CoreData.

```
-(void)getLocations{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"code": @"123"};
    [manager POST:@"website.com/getjson" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        response = responseObject;

        for (NSDictionary *obj in responseObject) {
            // Create any objects for Coredata here
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

Comment: hmm I did not realize that this was done for me already. Awesome I think I can get it from here! Thank you for explaining that to me

Answer (score 0):

Yes. NSJsonSerialization does the job. It converts the json to a NSDictionary.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356842/how-to-use-nsjsonserialization) gives you a fine example.

Comment: Well, in this case it converted the JSON into an NSArray (of NSDictionaries).  What you get is what's in the JSON -- it's not always the same.

Comment: So in this case how would I say, print/log the first name of the 1st result?

Comment: You have got an array of dictionaries.
NSDictionary *firstEntry = [parsedjson objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"%@", [firstEntry objectForKey:@"FIRST_NAME"];