# converting a NSString with JSON to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring

I have an `NSString` that looks like:

```
{
   "name": "anEvent",
      "args": [
      {
        "ct": "Un",
        "someUUID": "D7EC06DE-98D3-436F-A657-FB043567FB67",
        "userName": "Joe Smith",
        "long": "-139.724302",
        "lat": "39.402768"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get just the inner part

```
{
    "ct": "Un",
    "someUUID": "D7EC06DE-98D3-436F-A657-FB04383CFB67",
    "userName": "Joe Smith",
    "long": "-139.724305",
    "lat": "39.402768"
}
```

into an `NSDictionary`?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356842/how-to-use-nsjsonserialization).

Comment: can u give ur PHP url , I given the full answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
 NSDictionary *dictObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                           error:nil];
 NSDictionary *requiredObject = [[dictObj objectForKey:@"args"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: essentially what is given but with slight differences:
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *d = [NSJSONSerialization
                   JSONObjectWithData:[yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                              options:kNilOptions
                                error:&error];

Answer (score 5):

Deserialise the whole string, then use `objectForKey:@"args"` to drill in to the part you want.

Comment: this is also an answer, but just without sample code.