# How to add JSON parsed data in core data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am parsing data using `ASIHTTPRequest`. Now, I want to store that
data in core data. Used [this
API](http://sms.instatalkcommunications.com/apireq/GetSMSCategories?t=1&h=admin&param=1).
My Entity Name SMS and includes three atrributes Id,Name and IsActive.
This code to parse data.

```
-(void)DataRetireve
{
    deatilinfoarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:   
    @"http://sms.instatalkcommunications.com/apireq/GetSMSCategories?
    t=1&h=admin&param=1"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];``
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

    NSError *error;

    NSString *responseString = nil;

    if (!error)
    {
        responseString = [request responseString];

        SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init] ;

        NSMutableArray *jsondata = [parser objectWithString:responseString];
        NSMutableArray *jsondata1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
       info *myinfo=[[info alloc]init];
        for(int i=0;i<jsondata.count;i++)
        {

            myinfo.Id=@"Id";
            myinfo.Name=@"Name";
            myinfo.IsActive=@"IsActive";

            [jsondata1 addObject:myinfo];
             NSLog(@"%@",responseString);

        }
           for(int i=0;i<jsondata1.count;i++)
           {
            myinfo= [jsondata1 objectAtIndex:i];

                 NSManagedObjectContext *context=[self managedObjectContext];
               NSManagedObject *sms = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SMS" inManagedObjectContext:context];


               NSLog(@"%@", context);

               [sms setValue:@"Id" forKey:@"Id"];
               [sms setValue:@"Name" forKey:@"Name"];
               [sms setValue:@"IsActive" forKey:@"IsActive"];

               [jsondata1 addObject:myinfo];

            }
```

Done code for that but give me error

Comment: Sure, with this line of code NSManagedObjectContext *context; you haven't a valid managed object context. Take the right from AppDelegate or pass it to your relevant ViewController.

Comment: i pass this code -(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context=nil;
    id delegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    if([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)])
    {
        context=[delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

Comment: show me this error   int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: That's no error. Post the console log and set an exception breakpoint.

Comment: yes i set break point but the not shown any error

Comment: can you check that code once again?please

Comment: Place a NSLog pls. NSLog("%@", context);

Comment: where i place slog after  [jsondata1 addObject:myinfo];

Comment: i update the code and its run now but i am confuse its right or wrong......

Answer (score 1):

First, I think ASIHTTPRequest is kind of outdated. According to the [original site](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) was last modified on 2011. I recommend you to switch to http://afnetworking.com/ .

Now, regarding the JSON to Core Data. First, you should parse the JSON data using NSJSONSerialization. You can take a look at this question ([How to use NSJSONSerialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356842/how-to-use-nsjsonserialization)) for more information.

Then, create a new NSManagedObject for your entity:

```
NSManagedObject *aSMS = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SMS"
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

And then just set the values. Like:

```
aSMS.Name = JSON[@"Name"];
```

Comment: there is no error but i am confuse data added in the databse aur not