# how to parse json into struct in swift

Tags: json, parsing, swift

I have struct like this:

```
struct Company {

    let name:String
    let id:Int
}
```

I want to parse from JSON a set of Companies.

Can you please help me how can I do that in Swift?

Comment: You can use SwiftyJSON,  https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 1):

This is for future folks. In Swift 4 there is a very nice solution with `JSONDecoder`.

With Alamofire code will look like this -

```
Alamofire.request(Router.login(parameters: parameters)).responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result{
        case .success(_):
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            guard let _ = response.data else{
                return
            }
            do {
                let loginDetails = try decoder.decode(LoginDetails.self, from: response.data!)
                // get your details from LoginDetails struct
            } catch let err{
                print(err)
            }


        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder

https://medium.com/xcblog/painless-json-parsing-with-swift-codable-2c0beaeb21c1

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: `guard let _ ` is very bad syntax if you actually need the bound variable later.

Comment: I think the point here is how to decode a JSON to a struct. You can unwrap the optional whichever way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately JSON parsing is not very easy in swift.
You should use the [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html) class to do it.

There are plenty of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8356919/1700737) here to look at.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift3, It's possible to convert dictionary direct to struct use [MappingAce](https://github.com/IcyButterfly/MappingAce)

```
struct Company: Mapping {
    let name:String
    let id:Int
}

let companyInfo: [String : Any] = ["name" : "MappingAce", "id" : 1]

let company = Company(fromDic: companyInfo)
print(company.name)//"MappingAce"
print(company.id)  // 1
```