# nested dictionaries converted to json swift

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I Have a Dictionary of Dictionaries that I need to convert to Json.

```
[
    Dict1:1, 
    test: A Value, 
    NestedDict1:[
        city: A City Name, 
        address: An Address, 
        NestedDict2: [
            1: 1, 
            39: 2
        ],
        favorite1: 2, 
        favorite3: Chocolate
    ]
]
```

When I use the

```
NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(myJsonDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)
```

it only encodes the outer most dictionary. So my output looks something like this:

```
{
    "Dict1":"1", 
    "test": "A Value", 
    "NestedDict1":"[
        city: A City Name, 
        address: An Address, 
        NestedDict2: [
            1: 1, 
            39: 2
        ],
        favorite1: 2, 
        favorite3: Chocolate
    ]"
}
```

How do I JSON the inner dictionaries as well?

Comment: Try not passing `.PrettyPrinted` for the `options:` argument?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356842/how-to-use-nsjsonserialization

Comment: Why did someone vote it down? Looks a very valid question for me!!!

Comment: @ nhgrif tried without pretty print first, data ended up the same, just the outer gets encoded

Comment: @kbgn27 That link is actually for an array of dictionaries and doesnt seem the help with my problem of a dictionary of dictionaries

Comment: @BigJ Will the solution provided in this site help? http://blog.mailcloud.com/technology/apple-swift-code-strong-type-object-serialization-to-json/

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3

```
let myJsonDict : [String: Any] = [
    "Dict1": "1",
    "test": "A Value",
    "NestedDict1":[
        "city": "A City Name",
        "address": "An Address",
        "NestedDict2": [
            "1": "1",
            "39": "2"
        ],
        "favorite1": "2",
        "favorite3": "Chocolate"
    ]
]
let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: myJsonDict, options: [])

if let jsonString = String(data: jsonObject!, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(jsonString)
}
```

Output

> {"test":"A Value","Dict1":"1","NestedDict1":{"favorite1":2,"city":"A
>   City
>   Name","NestedDict2":{"1":"1","39":"2"},"favorite3":"Chocolate","address":"An
>   Address"}}

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is more with your representation of the data.

If you can get away with changing all the keys to Strings, then it can be a dictionary, since Strings conform to `Hashable`. Otherwise, it would be defined as `Any`, and can't really be a Dictionary key.

Doing this allows the following:

```
let myJsonDict : [String:AnyObject] = [
    "value": 1123,
    "test": "some string",
    "NestedDict1": [
        "city": "A City Name",
        "address": "An Address",
        "NestedDict2": [
            "1": 1,
            "39": 2
        ],
        "favorite1": 2,
        "favorite3": "Chocolate"
    ]
]

var jsonObject = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(myJsonDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)


println(NSString(data: jsonObject!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
```

which gives the following output:

```
{
  "test" : "some string",
  "NestedDict1" : {
    "city" : "A City Name",
    "address" : "An Address",
    "favorite3" : "Chocolate",
    "NestedDict2" : {
      "1" : 1,
      "39" : 2
    },
    "favorite1" : 2
  },
  "value" : 1123
}
```